# Why does arterial emboli flow in retrograde manner?

Tags: pathology

In artery blood flows with a pressure. When part of thrombus detaches it should flow along with the flow but it flows is retrograde manner.

Comment: Are you sure it does? Can you tell us where you learned this?

Comment: Yes it does. It is given in Asian edition of Robbins

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be talking about Propagation of arterial thrombi.

Propagation is the increasing size of a thrombus and it occurs towards the heart, this is because thrombi are formed differently in veins vs arteries. In veins they form through the accumulation of fibrin and red blood cells whilst in arteries they form through the clumping of platelets.

https://www.thrombosisadviser.com/thrombus-formation/

Embolization is when the clot is removed from the circulatory wall and at this point it moves along with blood flow in both veins and arteries.

Comment: Yes I'm talking about propagation. But venous embolus flows along with blood flow. My question is why does arterial embolus propogate in retrograde manner instead of flowing along with the blood flow?

Comment: @KetkiShah - An embolus is different than a thrombus. What are you asking? The answer is correct that emboli flow with blood, not against.

Comment: From a bit of searching on the internet the general opinion appears to be that it is due to the fact that arterial thrombi are formed differently to venous ones.

Arterial thrombi are caused by injury to the vascular wall, causing a clot of platelets to form at that point. These platelets begin to join the clot as they hit it, causing the clot to propagate retrograde (towards the direction the blood is coming from)

Venous thrombi are caused by stasis of the blood flow, this causes the blood to coagulate at the point and gradually more fibrin and red blood cells collect onto this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question after reading "arterial thrombi grow in a retrograde direction from the point of attachment, whereas venous thrombi extend in the direction of blood flow" from the Robbins & Kumar Basic Pathology Textbook. I think what this means is that the SIZE of the thrombus grows in the direction towards the aorta, but when it detaches it moves along the blood flow, so towards the right atrium of the heart. The reason why it grows towards the aorta is perhaps because blood is flowing towards the thrombus and the platelets get stuck on the thrombus before passing by it, so the plateles accumulate one after another. Think of it like a tube of flowing water with platelets. If the inside of the tube has some substance stuck to the wall of the tube, the platelets will sit on it before passing by it. I hope this helps!